# What's the difference between "use \namespace\Class" and "use namespace\Class" in PHP?

Tags: php, namespaces

Within our namespaced class files, there're various classes which have the namespace prefixed with a backslash and numerous others which don't.

Is there a difference between the two? Which is preferable to be using?

e.g.

`use namespace\ui\User`

vs

`use \namespace\ui\User`

where `namespace` itself represents the root folder where the namespaced classes reside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php):

> Note that for namespaced names (fully qualified namespace names containing namespace 
>   separator, such as Foo\Bar as opposed to global names that do not, such as FooBar), the 
>   **leading backslash is unnecessary and not recommended**, as *import names must be fully 
>   qualified*, and are not processed relative to the current namespace.

This means that you can, and should, omit the leading \ when importing/aliasing.

Answer (score 0):

how about if you use this method?

use

```
$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'\namespace\ui\User'
```